# The pronunciation of wondERful and bIRd

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonology

[image: Screenshot of IPA for bird]

[image: Screenshot of IPA for wonderful]

Hello,this is from the online Cambridge dictionary.

What I wondered is that why the vowel in *bird* and the second vowel in *wonderful* are different from each other?

What I think is that the vowel should be the same in the two words.But according to the dictionary,it is /ə/ "wonderful" while /ɜ/ in "bird".Why?

Comment: Why do you think that? Trying to force the vowel from *bird* into *wonderful* makes it sound unnatural in any English I'm familiar with.

Comment: @ChrisH OP was talking about the second syllable in *wonderful* not the first!

Comment: @Araucaria I know.  Unnatural rather than unheard of, because If you were stressing *wonderful* it could come out that long

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is a duplicate of every other question asking "Why is X pronounced like Y?"

Comment: @HotLicks No, the question is why they're transcribed with  different symbols when the two sounds have exactly the same vowel quality.

Comment: Wait...are you asking about British or American English? That entry says the American pronunciations are the same. Anyway, 'bird' is stressed but 'der' in 'wonderful' is not, giving a slightly different character in BrE or AmE

Comment: Very similar: [Pronunciation of “er” in “farmer” vs. “earth”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37571/pronunciation-of-er-in-farmer-vs-earth)

Comment: Also related: [Difference between IPA ɚ, ɹ, and ɝ](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192979)

Answer (score 6):

In standard Englishes, the vowel qualities of the SCHWA and NURSE vowels, /ə/ and /ɜ:/ respectively, are virtually identical as shown on this vowel diagram:

[image]

However, although these vowels are very similar in quality they are different phonemes. The NURSE vowel that we find in the word *bird* nearly always occurs in stressed syllables. SCHWA, on the other hand occurs exclusively in unstressed syllables. It will usually be much shorter in duration than an occurrence of the NURSE vowel.

If you tried to pronounce *wonderful* with a sustained second syllable, for example if you made the second syllable two or three seconds long, you would find the vowel to be indistinguishable from the vowel in *bird*.

Comment: This answer is about British English. The OP's tag is American English, where aside from the stress on the syllable, the two vowels are completely indistinguishable in many dialects.

Comment: @PeterShor Well, that's pretty much what I thought I was saying? In any standard Englishes those vowels will have the same quality (regardless of any /r/-coloring). The only perceivable difference will be the probable length of the vowel.

Comment: I believe the length distinctions in vowels in British English are quite a bit larger than those in American English.

Comment: According to the [Chinese wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%8E%E5%9B%BD%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD),stressed er is marked as /ɜ/ and not stressed as /ə/

Comment: @zzzgoo It's really more the case that both /ɜ/ and /ə/ are often represented by ER in the writing :)

Answer (score 0):

The word bird  and wonderful both make use of centering vowels but the only difference is in the length of the two vowels.In comparison to 'wonderful', the word 'bird' had a long centering vowel.wonderful has a schwa in it